# Changing from apacite to natbib package

Tags: citing, natbib, cite-package

I'm currently using the `apacite`-package for references in my thesis. However, I'd like to change the format of the references, which is currently on the form (Author, Year), to numbered style citation within square brackets ([10] for instance).

Looking at the documentation of the `apacite` package, it seems that it doesn't support this format. Instead, I'm looking to change to the `natbib` package. Can I do this without too much effort? For instance, can I use the same bib-file?

I tried changing the `apacite` referencing commands `\cite` or `\citeauthor` & `\citeyear` to `\citep` and `\citet`, respectively. However, I ended up with a lot of Undefined control sequence errors. Not sure where the problem lies, is it within the bib-file or is there something I am missing in the main TeX-file?

Edit: To illustrate, here's an example of what happens. I previously used the following code to reference an article: `\cite{Dempster1977}` or `\citeauthor{Dempster1977} \citeyear{Dempster1977}` depending on the format I wanted it on. This would result in the following references (Dempster et al., 1977) or Dempster et al. (1977).

Now I would instead have the following format:
Just the numbered of the reference in squared bracket, e.g. [10] or
Dempster et al. [10].

Here's the reference in the `.bib`-file.

```
 @article{Dempster1977,
author = "Dempster, A. P. and Laird, N. M. and Rubin, D. B.",
year = "1977",
title = "{Maximum Likelihood from Incomplete Data via the EM algorithm}",
journal = "{Journal of the Royal Statistical Society}",
volume = "39",
pages = "1--38"}
```

To get this format, I tried using the `natbib`-package. So I include (after removing `\usepackage{apacite}) \usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}`.

Then, in accordance with the documentation, I use `\citep{Demspter1977}` or `\citet{Dempster1977}`. But the error message for the line where I use `\citet{Dempster1977}` is

```
Undefined control sequence ...the seminal paper by \citet{Dempster1977}
Undefined control sequence ...the seminal paper by \citet{Dempster1977}
Missing = inserted for \ifnum ...the seminal paper by \citet{Dempster1977}
Missing number, treated as zero ...the seminal paper by \citet{Dempster1977}
```

These error messages appear throughout the file. Not sure what is causing them. Also, in the end I previously used

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

but I've changed this to

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}.
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal working example (MWE) including two bib entrys (use package `filecontents` to include it into your code ...). That helps us to find a solution for you ...

Comment: Typically, if you wish to keep document flexibility like this, you have to implement this before writing your document. Something that will more likely work is to define commands \mycite \myciteA \myciteB etc., with the property that it uses a particular reference style and package loading commands based on how the boolean is set.

Comment: In any case, a minimal example will go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Here's what I'd do. I'm very picky about how citations are handled, so I'm going for fine grained control over how each of the citations is in handled in and outside of text by specifying a boolean and self-made citation commands. Switching the boolean sometimes requires you to plow throw errors, but these will resolve after running through the full document once (just to be sure: this will require you to continue compilation regardless of the errors. If you have over 100 citations, remove your aux and bib files).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifnatbib \natbibfalse

\ifnatbib
  \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \let\mycitep\citep
  \let\mycitet\citet
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\else
  \usepackage[apaciteclassic]{apacite}
  \let\mycitep\cite
  \let\mycitet\citeA
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\fi
\let\mycite\cite

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{KamerlinghOnnes:1911p1320,
author = {Heike Kamerlingh-Onnes}, 
journal = {Communications from the Physical Laboratory of the University of Leiden},
title = {Further experiments with liquid Helium G. On the electrical resistance of pure metals, etc. VI. On the sudden change in the rate at which the resistance of Mercury disappears},
pages = {799--802},
volume = {124},
year = {1911},
month = {Feb},
date-added = {2009-02-05 11:13:59 +0100},
date-modified = {2011-10-05 15:29:37 +0200},
local-url = {file://localhost/Users/Shared/AndyDropbox/Dropbox/Library/Papers/1911/Kamerlingh-Onnes/Communications%20from%20the%20Physical%20Laboratory%20of%20the%20University%20of%20Leiden1911%20124%20799-802.pdf},
uri = {papers://1C9DCAE7-AE34-4220-9FE3-8B3A37855B8A/Paper/p1320},
rating = {0}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

A reference\mycite{KamerlinghOnnes:1911p1320}. \mycitet{KamerlinghOnnes:1911p1320} said that and that, but I don't agree because of this and that.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing bibliography entries in a BiBTeX database (.bib file) in this format, you should be good to go:

```
@book{Author1991,
    author    = "Author",
    title     = "How I met your mother",
    something = "Something"
}
```

Then you can load the natbib package instead of apacite with any options you want, maybe `\usepackage[square]{natbib}` would be a good start for the [N] style citations. Then you need to specify the desired style (.bst file) in the document. Abbrv style, which comes directly with the package outputs citations in the [number] format. Then you load references like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{my-bib-file}
```

And then you normally compile the document with pdflatex or other compiler, then bibtex and pdflatex twice.

If you are interested in the look of different citation styles available in natbib package, you can refer to: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html
or: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib
if you are interested in more detailed information on the natbib package.

Also, have you tried deleting the .aux and .bbl file after changing apacite to natbib package? That helped me with a few bibliography related errors so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to natbib, it is necessary to delete .aux and .bbl files since they contain the non-natbib information and the package complains about it.

Comment: really? if you make standard procedure (LaTeX, BibLaTeX, LaTeX, LaTex) to produce reference this should not be a case. Do I miss something?